# check for duplicates in diffrent worksheets and thereafter print value

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched but i cant seem to figure out how to print specified value in the column next to where i find my duplicate. What i have since earlier are code that first specify the diffrent ranges and thereafter look if a duplicate is found in sheet Y from sheet X. Sheet Le is this weeks information and sheet Be is the last weeks information.

IF i find a duplicate in the specified range i want to on my Delivery sheet print in column A next to the duplicate either Delivered or not delivered depending on if my output from function compareAEO print true or false.

The conditions that i am looking for are that if the we can find the same value that are in column B in sheet (Le) on sheet (Be) it will then check if the text in column F has changed. IF SO then it shall print in column A on sheet (Le) = Delivered. Otherwise not delivered.

It then checks to se if the dates in column M is the same. IF not then it shall print Replanned in column A on sheet (Le).

Shortly 
IF value in cell on column B, Sheet (Le) = Value in column B, Sheet (Be) then
value in column A on sheet Le = "Delivered" Else "not deliverd".

Then

If value in cell in column M, Sheet (Le) <> If value in cell in column M, Sheet (Be) then value in column A, Sheet(Le) = "replanned"

This is how my data looks like, 
Sheet (Le)

```
Col B   Col F    Col M
PZ2408  X13    2017-02-13
PZ2345  X30    2017-02-23
PZ2463  X45    2017-02-25
PZ2513  X13    2017-02-10
PZ2533  X70    2017-02-05
PZ2561  X60    2017-02-20
```

For sheet (Be) my data looks like this

```
Col B   Col F    Col M
PZ2408  X30    2017-02-13
PZ2345  X30    2017-02-23
PZ2463  X30    2017-02-25
PZ2513  X13    2017-02-05
PZ2533  X13    2017-02-10
PZ2561  X60    2017-02-17
```

After the code has done its course i would like it to show for example,

Sheet (Le)

```
    col A           Col B   Col F    Col M
   Delivered       PZ2408   X13    2017-02-13
Not Delivered      PZ2345   X30    2017-02-23
   Delivered       PZ2463   X45    2017-02-25
  replanned        PZ2513   X13    2017-02-10
   Delivered       PZ2533   X70    2017-02-05
   replanned       PZ2561   X60    2017-02-20
```

Bascilly my Not delivered, delivered and Replanned statements does not work and my brain does not work.

Can SO help save my day?

```
Sub checkASMT()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim lastRowSource As Long
Dim lastRowTarget As Long
Dim row As Long
Dim ASMT As String

'Looping trough Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Le")

   lastRowTarget = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   For i = 29 To lastRowTarget
        ASMT = .Range("b" & i).value
        'Define range and see if we can find duplicates
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Be")
            lastRowSource = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
            Set rng1 = .Range("B3", "B" & lastRowSource)

            row = findValueInRangeReturnRow(rng1, ASMT)


            'Check FAX 
            If compareAEO(i, row, "FAX") = True Then
                'Debug.Print compareASMT(i, row, "FAX")
                Worksheets("Le").Cells(i, ASMT).value = "Not Delivered"

                Else

                .Worksheets("Le").Cells(i, ASMT).value = "delivered"

                'Check if dax are correct
                If compareAEO(i, row, "DAX") = False Then
                .Worksheets("Le").ASMT.Offset(0, 1).value = "Replan"


            End If



        End With
    Next i

End With


 End Sub
```

here are my first function

```
 Function findValueInRangeReturnRow(rng As Range, value As Variant) As Long

        Set c = rng.Find(value, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then

            findValueInRangeReturnRow = c.row

        End If

End Function
```

My second function that checks if duplicates are found in specified ranges.

```
Function compareAEO(rad1 As Variant, rad2 As Variant, typeCOMPARE As String) As Boolean

Dim col1 As String
Dim col2 As String

  Select Case typeCOMPARE
    Case "FAX"
        col1 = "F"
        col2 = "F"

    Case "DAX"
        col1 = "M"
        col2 = "M"

    End Select

   If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Le").Range(col1 & rad1).value =   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Be").Range(col2 & rad2).value Then

    compareAEO = True
    Else

    compareAEO = False
End If



End Function
```

Comment: It'd help you showed your data "structure" and and example of wanted output

Comment: Edited my post in regards to your comment! Thank u!

Comment: You may want to add a final state of data after a run of the "good" macro

Comment: Done and done Sir!

Comment: There are several issues in your code as posted surrounding the `If` statements. 1. what is `Check FAX`, should this be a comment? 2. Is `compareASMTECOPART` defined separately somewhere, or should this be `compareAEO`? 3. Your "DAX" `If` block doesn't have a corresponding `End If`. 4. `.Worksheets("Le").ASMT.Offset(0, 1).value = "Replan"` won't work as there shouldn't be a `.` in front of `Worksheets` and `ASMT` is a `String`, not a `Range`.

Comment: Also, if you are replying to someone's comment, you should "@" them so they see your reply, e.g. "@DL1".

Comment: @DL1, Can you please edit your answer to tell us the exact conditions that must exist for the three different conclusions, Delivered, Not Delivered, and Replanned?  It would be easier for me to start from scratch on the code.

Comment: @JohnMuggins i have tried my best to edit my question regarding ur input. Hopefully u will know now what i am looking for. Thank u for ur input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting the last row of both pages in each loop.  It is only necessary to get them once at the top, outside the loop.  Same for the range you were setting.  You can see that I put them at the top, before the loop.

I don't really know what you were using ASMT for.  It looks like you were trying to use it as a range in some of your coding instead of range("B" & I).  I used strings in the "B" column of Le to compare to the "B" column of Be when I tested it.

It works for me.  You'll have to change it to suit your needs.  You don't need all the functions, what they accomplished are all within this subroutine.

```
Sub checkASMT()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim lastRowLE As Long
Dim lastRowBe As Long
Dim row As Long
Dim ASMT As String
Dim LEws As Worksheet
Dim tmpRng As Range

    Set LEws = Worksheets("Le")
    lastRowLE = Sheets("Le").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    lastRowBe = Sheets("Be").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    Set rng1 = Sheets("Be").Range("B3", "B" & lastRowBe)


   For i = 29 To lastRowLE
        Set tmpRng = Sheets("Le").Range("b" & i)
        ASMT = tmpRng.Value

        Set c = rng1.Find(ASMT, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
                row = c.row
                If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Le").Range("F" & i).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Be").Range("F" & row).Value Then
'                    Worksheets("Le").Cells(i, ASMT).Value = "Not Delivered"
'                   Did you intend to use ASMT as the column number?
'                   I'm going to hard code that as column 27 for my purposes.  You can change it if you need to
                    LEws.Cells(i, 27).Value = "Not Delivered"   ' column 27 is "AA"
                Else
                    LEws.Cells(i, 27).Value = "Delivered"
                End If
                If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Le").Range("M" & i).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Be").Range("M" & row).Value Then
'                    .Worksheets("Le").ASMT.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Replan"
'                       again I don't understand the reference to ASMT.  That is a string value - unless it is a numeric value in the string
'                       I'm going to assume that you intended for "Replan" to go into column C on row i
                Else
                    LEws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Replan"
                End If
         End If
    Next i



 End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! @John_Muggins  U are a VBA God! A huge thanks. Do u have any recommendations how i tackle VBA to become a really good programmer?

Comment: Keep chugging at it.  Also when you get routines that work, save them to a special module you can insert to future projects and have them handy.  Finding the last used row is a simple code but after 30 years of programming I still need to look up how to do it every time.  By keeping it in my special module I never have to go far to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this; place data in single sheet from B to G (Le then Be); place this formula in column H

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(E2,B$2:D$7,2,FALSE)=F2,IF(G2<D2,"replanned","Not Delivered"),"delivered")
```

tweak this formula to suit your needs to make it work across sheets

Comment: Thank u!! @user2648008 Will check as soon as i am at the Office in 1 hour:) i am so stuck with this one.... Hopefully this Will do the trick. For my learning purpose does annons have an VBA way to do IT aswell?

Comment: this got me in the right direction.I finished up with 2 diffrent formulas that i made in helper columns and then had a vba code to copy from those column to column a.